# How far can one be from an helipad when marshalling an helicopter?

Tags: helicopter, regulations, ground-operations

I considered 25 meters (as per UN SOP's) but after working years with MI-8's the downwash can flatten a big man. I'm interested in procedures from the FAA etc. ...

Comment: I'm not sure the FAA has regulations regarding this. There is a chapter in the [FAA Helicopter Flying Handbook](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/helicopter_flying_handbook/media/hfh_ch08.pdf) about ground safety, but no specific distances are called out. Only that it would be difficult to develop one policy for all helicopters.

Comment: This question is incomplete: are you only concerned with MI-8's?  If so, make sure you question says exactly that.  Size matters.  If you want a general rule, the question is too broad (per @RonBeyer comment)

Comment: Can't find any rules about marshaling helicopters in Canada other than the signals themselves, If its an air operator the "AOC" once approved is considered law, so any any restrictions in that document would be considered regulation in Canada. As for an FOB, nothing found for Canada.